# An optimization method for bounding the spectral radii of a unknown non symmetric matrix and its inverse

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

Given a positive objective function $f$ that acts on a real-valued matrix $A$, I am interested in the following problem

$$\underset{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}{\text{minimize}} \quad f(A) \quad \text{subject to} \quad \rho \left(A^{-1}\right) \leq 1-\epsilon, \quad \rho(A) \leq 1+\epsilon \ ,$$

where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius. What optimization methods are available for approaching this task?

I know there are several techniques for bounding the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices, but I wonder what happens in the non-symmetric case (my $A$ is not necessarily symmetric).

Comment: Also posted at SciComp: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33217/20417

Comment: I edited my question, now having slightly different conditions. Does this change allow for effective optimization? What about relaxing the constraints so that one bounds the Frobenius norm of the matrix and its inverse?

Comment: What is $f$? It would be mighty convenient if you can split $f$ into a part depending on the spectrum and one depending on the eigenvectors, say...

Comment: $f$ could be many things; a simple example might be $f(A) = |AX-Y|_F^2$, where $X, Y$ are given matrices and $|\cdot|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. For general $f$, I do not think I will have such a split

Answer (score 2):

You could formulate the spectral radius condition using the 2-norm, for example, to obtain an upper bound:
$$ \rho(A)\leq ||A||_2$$
You can then formulate $ \rho(A)\leq1+\epsilon$  as
$$A^T A \preceq (1+\epsilon)^2 I \Leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}I & A \\ A^T  &(1+\epsilon)^2 I \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0,$$
where I used the Schur complement in the second step. Similarly, for $ \rho(A^{-1})\leq1-\epsilon$ you obtain
$$\begin{bmatrix}I & A^{-1} \\ A^{-T}  &(1-\epsilon)^2 I \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}A A^T & I \\ I  &(1-\epsilon)^2 I \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0,$$
where I pre- and post-multiplied with diag$(A, I)$ and its transpose, respectively.

If your objective function is convex, then with the first constraint you will have a convex optimization problem. The second constraint, however, is bilinear. You can model the problem using e.g. YALMIP (free) and solve it using e.g. PENlab (free).

Check [Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/lmibook/lmibook.pdf).

Note that you might get a better result if you use $ \rho(A)\leq \min_D||D^{-1} A D||_2$, where $D$ is any invertible matrix, but usually chosen to be diagonal.